# Using DATEADD in the where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to use the DATEADD function in my where clause. Below is the following code and the error I get is below it. Does anyone know what the problem could be?

```
select e.GenProdIdent, e.GenericLaunchDate, DATEADD(month, -12, min(e.GenericLaunchDate)) TwelveMosPrior, SUM(WACDollars) from ErosionData2 e
join mddb m on m.GenProdIdent = e.GenProdIdent
join wkdata2 w on w.NDC11 = m.NDC
where m.RepckgCode <> 'x' and w.recorddate between DATEADD(month, -12, min(w.recorddate)) and e.GenericLaunchDate and e.genprodident = '44505080000320'

group by e.GenProdIdent,
e.GenericLaunchDate
```

Msg 147, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.

Comment: It relates to your use of the Min() function and not DateAdd()

Comment: Ahh I just realized that as I was coming back to report my findings. Thanks!